# После переназначения ссылки в методе на новый объект, переданная ссылка продолжает ссылаться на прежний объект

Tags: java, классы, объекты

Пример с сайта Quizful.net:

```
public class Test {
    private void method1() {
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        obj.x = 1;
        method2(obj);
        System.out.println("obj.x="+obj.x);
    }

    private void method2(MyClass param) {
        param.x = 2;
        param = new MyClass();  //1
        param.x = 3;
    }

    class MyClass {
        int x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().method1();
    }
}

OUTPUT: obj.x=2
```

**Вопросы:** Почему 2, а не 3? Что за магия произошла в месте, которое я пометил `//1`единицей в комментариях?

**UPDATE:** правильный и короткий ответ - при вызове метода с непримитивным аргументом,  в метод передаётся не объект, не ссылка, а копия ссылки на область памяти где этот объект хранится. Метод 2 компилятор понял (примерно) так:

```
 private void method2(MyClass param) { //Пусть param - исходная ссылка на объект
        MyClass paramCopy = param; //java работает на самом деле с копией переданной ссылки
        paramCopy.x = 2;
        paramCopy = new MyClass();  //1
        paramCopy.x = 3;
    }
```

Comment: Объекты передаются в методы не просто по ссылке, а по значению ссылки - т.е при возвращении значения из метода все переданные в качестве аргументов ссылки на обекты БУДУТ указывать на те же объекты, на которые они указывали перед вызовом.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

param по сути является указателем на объект класса.

```
param.x = 2;
```

в этой строчке мы изменили объект, который был создан выше в method1

```
param = new MyClass();
```

param изменился, он указывает на новый объект.
И у нового объекта мы меняем значение x.
Но obj не менялся. Он по-прежнему указывает на первый объект!

Comment: Нельзя менять параметр функции, можно только то, на что он указывает. Параметр передается по значению.

Comment: Всё всё всё допёрло после вашего разъяснения. Спасибо.

Comment: Галочку снимать, или минусовать не буду. В UPDATE поместил то, что нужно было правильно ответить. В метод передаётся [копия ссылки](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.14.php) 
а так ответ очень поверхностен.

Comment: А зачем вы обратились к вопросу 2годичной давности? Я уже давно забыла, что там было.

Comment: Потому что подрос и вспомнил, что задавал подобное.

Comment: Очень рада, задавайте любые вопросы по Java.

Answer (score 2):

Разбираем все по ОООПически:

1) Создается ссылка в куче для obj

```
 MyClass obj = new MyClass();
```

2) Ссылка содержит указатель на значение в куче 1, присвоенное:

```
obj.x = 1
```

3) Меняем содержимое на которое указывает ссылка obj на 2:

```
param.x = 2;
```

4) Новый объект создается param , в ссылке obj по-прежнему 2

```
param = new MyClass();  //1
param.x = 3;
```

Comment: Всё так, спасибо. Предыдущий оратор просто разъяснил более понятно.